# How do I rename columns in a python pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

i'm new to pandas and was wondering if someone can help me out.

- i have written the code shown below.
- the contents of the json files are pasted below the script.
- below the json contents we can see the script output.

i would simply like to set the name of each column in the output dataframe as the name of the country object (eg. Germany or France)

instead of getting this output

```
                  value    name        value     name
tag                                                  
capital           Paris  France       Berlin  Germany
population  34111000000  France  11233000000  Germany
language         French  France       German  Germany
```

...i would like something like this

```
                  France             Germany     
tag                                                  
capital           Paris         Berlin  Germany
population  34111000000    11233000000  Germany
language         French         German  Germany
```

any help would be appreciated : - )

here is my code...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json

class Country(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.json = name + "_Data.json"

def ImportJson(x):
    ImportedJson = []
    for country in x:
        with open(country.json) as country_json_file:
            country_data = json.load(country_json_file)
            country_data_table = pd.DataFrame(country_data['data'], columns=['tag', 'value']).set_index('tag')
            country_data_table['name'] = country.name
        ImportedJson.append(country_data_table)
    return ImportedJson

France = Country("France")
Germany = Country("Germany")
All_Countries = [France,Germany]

OpenedJson = ImportJson(All_Countries)

Country_Data = pd.concat(OpenedJson,axis=1)
print Country_Data
```

here are the json files

Germany_Data.json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "tag": "capital",
            "value": "Berlin"
        },
        {
            "tag": "population",
            "value": 11233000000
        },
        {
            "tag": "language",
            "value": "German"
        }
    ],
    "result_count": 33,
    "page_size": 5000,
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "api_call_credits": 1
}
```

France_Data.json

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "tag": "capital",
            "value": "Paris"
        },
        {
            "tag": "population",
            "value": 34111000000
        },
        {
            "tag": "language",
            "value": "French"
        }
    ],
    "result_count": 33,
    "page_size": 5000,
    "current_page": 1,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "api_call_credits": 1
}
```

script output

```
                  value    name        value     name
tag                                                  
capital           Paris  France       Berlin  Germany
population  34111000000  France  11233000000  Germany
language         French  France       German  Germany
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function `ImportJson` you have the following two lines of code.

```
country_data_table = pd.DataFrame(country_data['data'], columns=['tag', 'value']).set_index('tag')
country_data_table['name'] = country.name
```

Delete the second line and add this directly after it

```
country_data_table.rename(columns={'value':country.name}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This gives me a `DF` with all `NaNs`. Maybe you meant to do - `country_data_table.rename(columns={'value':country.name}, inplace=True)` instead of the second line.

Answer (score 2):

***I rewrote your `class`***

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json

class Country(object):
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.json = name + "_Data.json"
        with open(self.json, 'r') as fp:
            self.data = json.load(fp)['data']
        self.series = pd.DataFrame.from_records(
            self.data
        ).set_index('tag').value.rename(self.name)

France = Country("France")
Germany = Country("Germany")


pd.concat([c.series for c in [France, Germany]], axis=1)

                 France      Germany
tag                                 
capital           Paris       Berlin
population  34111000000  11233000000
language         French       German
```

---

***if you insisted on manipulating your constructed dataframe***

```
# take transpose so I can groupby index and add a count column
# for each `name` and `value`.  Once I have a unique index, I can
# do more.
CD1 = Country_Data.T.set_index(
    Country_Data.T.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), append=True).T

# strategy is to filter `value` columns and reassign the columns
CD2 = CD1.filter(like='value')
CD2.columns = Country_Data.loc['capital', 'name'].tolist()

CD2

                 France      Germany
tag                                 
capital           Paris       Berlin
population  34111000000  11233000000
language         French       German
```

---

***setup `json` files***

```
import json

with open('Germany_Data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "tag": "capital",
                    "value": "Berlin"
                },
                {
                    "tag": "population",
                    "value": 11233000000
                },
                {
                    "tag": "language",
                    "value": "German"
                }
            ],
            "result_count": 33,
            "page_size": 5000,
            "current_page": 1,
            "total_pages": 1,
            "api_call_credits": 1
        }
        , fp)

with open('France_Data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(
        {
            "data": [
                {
                    "tag": "capital",
                    "value": "Paris"
                },
                {
                    "tag": "population",
                    "value": 34111000000
                },
                {
                    "tag": "language",
                    "value": "French"
                }
            ],
            "result_count": 33,
            "page_size": 5000,
            "current_page": 1,
            "total_pages": 1,
            "api_call_credits": 1
        }
        , fp)
```